# Custom TabBarController functionality

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls

I'm attempting to create a custom tab bar controller with the following options:

1. Feed
2. Map
3. New
4. Camera
5. Search

The feed, map, camera, and search will each pull up their individual VC's, while new is supposed to be more of a functionality button. When the new tab item is pressed, the map view should be displayed, and the map should begin recording the user's location. I'm trying to use a `UITabBarController` to manage these views, but I cannot seem to figure out how to implement the functionality that I would like with the "New" tab. It seems as if I would need to implement a separate view controller for the "New" record and stop functionality but that doesn't seem right.

The functionality of record/stop should be similar to snapchat's big red button that takes a picture when you press it.

Comment: Isn't it more intuitive for the user to just go to the map tab and add a "new" button? It would for me, at least. Apple does not recommend jumping to tabs on the user's behalf.

Comment: the idea behind the app is for recording and sharing "scenic" routes and pictures around the user. I've been using POP (prototyping on paper, a free app in the app store) to throw together wireframes and prototypes to test UX, and having the button right in the middle of the tab bar felt much more natural to begin recording routes than having a NavBar item that says "New" on the feed or map.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, having two different maps can be confusing for the user, especially if they do almost the exact same thing. I think I would put the map tab in the middle position and create a big button as a map overlay. I had a map-based app as well, with multiple tabs and multiple maps, but eventually decided it was much easier to create one map tab on which the user could do whatever s/he needed. If you still think that's the way to go, then you can consider view controller containment (a new feature in iOS 6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree with [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751268/scott)'s comment that this is a bad UX, if you technically wanted to do it, you could subclass `UITabBarController` and in `viewDidLoad` you could add a `UIButton` subview to the the tab bar controller's `tabBar`:

```
[self.tabBar addSubview:yourCustomButton];
```

Thus, this button could have it's own action and selector to do whatever you want with.

Take a look at [idevrecipes](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement the container view controller yourself. I think you can't do that with UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to dig up the idevrecipes example that shawnwall pointed out, but there's another possibly answer, assuming you want the New button to match the standard UITabBarButton appearance. I agree it may not be the best UI, but it's workable.

For starters, you would create a dummy view controller for the New item. I'm not saying you should duplicate the Maps controller or anything, I'm just saying create an empty view controller and stash to it (or it's location) in a property. Assuming you're creating your tab bar in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, it'd look something like this.

```
self.newViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.newViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"New", nil);
self.newViewController.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"new.png"];
```

Drop that view controller at the appropriate location in the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property.

Save a reference to the Maps controller the same way you saved one for the dummy New controller.

If you haven't already done do, set the delegate of your tabBarController to your app delegate. You may need to declare that your app delegate conforms to `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

`UITabBarDelegate` gives you a few hooks for tracking changes to the tab bar. `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` looks to be the appropriate place for us to hook in for your desired behavior.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isEqual:self.newViewController]) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.mapViewController;
        // Whatever logic you need to start the recording
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The look of the user interaction's a little odd - the user tabs the middle item (New), but the item to the left (Map) gets selected. If you want the "tab bar triggers behavior" action, I'd go the idevrecipes route and make the button visually distinct. If you're married to the tab bar item look, though, I believe this is how you'd accomplish it.