# UITabBarController in Storyboard with BarItem without view controll

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I need a baritem that just execute some code without going to a view controller. Is this possible?

I started a project using the TabBar Controller template and the storyboard shows the tabbar controller with 2 views ( first view, and second view)

what I want to do is add a third bar item and have it call a function in some .m file  how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`. In it, you execute the code you want to execute and then at the end return `NO`. Your code will be executed, but you stay on the screen you are on.

Note though, that this is not very common UI design and you should really consider a different approach. See this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046331/custom-tabbarcontroller-functionality) for some more discussion on the topic as well.